# How to Communicate Between Server and Client using Bottle and Socket (Online)

Tags: python, sockets

I'm using Bottle, socket and serial to communicate between a client and server to turn on a motor. This code works great on my machine, but when I try to bring it online, I get a network connection error. I've been told that I should be using websockets for this and not sockets (to avoid trying to use an IP only), but have no idea where to start on implementing websockets. I am looking for any advice, with examples to help me get this online. I host at PythonAnywhere.com and have socket support for my account.

**Server.py**

```
from socket import *
import serial
host = ''
port = 7000
our_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
our_socket.bind((host, port))
our_socket.listen(1) 
conn, addr = our_socket.accept()

print ('Received motor start request from ' + str(addr))
data = conn.recv(1024)
arduinoData = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem1421',9600)
arduinoData.write("1".encode())
reply = input("Hit 1 to allow motor request: ")
conn.send(bytes(reply,'UTF-8'))
data = conn.recv(1024)
arduinoData = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem1421',9600)
arduinoData.write("1".encode())
reply = input()
conn.send(bytes(reply,'UTF-8'))
data = conn.recv(1024)
arduinoData = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem1421',9600)
arduinoData.write("0".encode())

conn.close()
```

**Client.py**

```
import bottle
from bottle import run, get, post, request, route, error, default_app
from socket import * 
import serial
host = ''
port = 7000

@route('/system')
def login():
    return '''

    <form action="/system" method="post" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned">
        <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Connect</button>
    </form>

    '''

@route('/system', method='POST')
def syson():
    our_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    our_socket.connect((host, port))
    message = "go"
    our_socket.send(bytes(message,'UTF-8'))
    reply = our_socket.recv(1024)
    message = "go"
    our_socket.send(bytes(message,'UTF-8'))
    reply = our_socket.recv(1024)
    return bottle.redirect("/system")

run(host='localhost', port=8000)
```

**How it Appears to Me**

My code is primitive and simple, but works so far. For the online issue, it seems that the only thing missing here is a way to connect to my local machine. I would have thought it was as simple as an IP, but there seems to be issues with that.

**ASCII Diagram**

*What works:*

Client.py (offline bottle site) <-----> Server.py (on my machine) ------> Arduino IDE

*What's not working:*

Internet ------> Client.py (online @ PythonAnywhere) <-----> Server.py (on my machine) ------> Arduino IDE

Thank you

Comment: Either you misunderstood the advice, or someone was giving you really weird advice. There's nothing wrong with using plain ol' sockets. You're running on PythonAnywhere, but I'm assuming you also have something running on your local machine? Can you draw an ascii diagram of your server relationship? Something as simple as `internet ------> pythonanywhere <-------> local machine ---> thing with motors`, for example.

Comment: Yes, I'll create one and add it to the original question. Thank you.

Comment: quick question- is your offline client.py running from within the same network as server.py? ie. is server.py open to the internet?

Comment: Hi conrad. The offline client and server are both sitting on my computer for the code that works. When I try to bring the client online and connect out to the "server.py", I cannot connect to it.

Comment: I think Conrad was asking whether you've set things up so that computers on the Internet can connect to server.py on your own local machine.  That's something you'd probably need to configure explicitly -- for example, if it's at home, you'd need to configure your router.  If you're using an organisation's network, it's something you can ask the network admins about.  One easy way to check -- if the IP address you're using for the machine running the server is something like 192.168.X.Y then it's a local address that isn't accessible from the public Internet.

Comment: Hi Giles. Okay, that makes sense. Let me take that and go and do some self-study on it. Thanks again.